# Flutter/Firebase Dynamic Link is no valid email link

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

For a flutter app I'm trying to setup an email-link authentification to sign in users.
That's my code so far for sending an email and receiving a link:

FireBaseAuthService:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:test/src/features/auth/application/auth_service.dart';

class FirebaseAuthService implements AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  bool isSignInWithEmailLink(String link) {
    return _firebaseAuth.isSignInWithEmailLink(link);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> sendSignInWithEmailLink({
    required String email,
  }) async {
    return await _firebaseAuth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(
      email: email,
      actionCodeSettings: ActionCodeSettings(
        url: 'https://test.page.link/signUp',
        handleCodeInApp: true,
        iOSBundleId: 'com.test.ios',
        androidPackageName: 'com.test.android',
        androidInstallApp: true,
        androidMinimumVersion: '12',
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {}
}
```

And my FirebaseEmailLinkHandler to handle incoming deepLinks:

```
import 'package:firebase_dynamic_links/firebase_dynamic_links.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

class FirebaseEmailLinkHandler extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<void>> {
  //constructor
  FirebaseEmailLinkHandler(this.ref) : super(const AsyncData(null));
  final Ref ref;

  //init dynamic links
  Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
    //get initial link
    final PendingDynamicLinkData? initialLink =
        await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();

    if (initialLink != null) {
      final Uri? deepLink = initialLink.link;
      if (deepLink != null) {
        //sign in with email and link
        print("Initial link: ${deepLink.path}");
      }
    }

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink.listen((pendingDynamicLinkData) {
      if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
        final Uri? deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData?.link;

        ref
            .read(authServiceProvider)
            .isSignInWithEmailLink(deepLink.toString());

        ref.read(authServiceProvider).signInWithEmailAndLink(
            email: 'test@googlemail.com', link: deepLink.toString());
      }
    });
  }
}

final firebaseEmailLinkHandlerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<FirebaseEmailLinkHandler, AsyncValue<void>>((ref) {
  return FirebaseEmailLinkHandler(ref);
});
```

I'm currently receiving a link, but the link I'm getting back is no valid email link, when i check it with the FirebaseAuth-Method isSignInWithEmailLink(link) it outputs false.
When i print the deepLink it prints the link configured in the firebase dynamic links console under the label Deeplink-URL.

What am I doing wrong? What else can i try? Do i have to configure something different in the firebase dynamic link console?

Edit: the link i receive via email looks correctly formatted, when i receive it in app the queryparamters like "oobcode" and "mode" are cut and i am left with a simple url which fails to be a valid e-mail link obviously.

Comment: I'm having the same issues! I feel like I've tried everything. I'm also only having issues on Android, not iOS.